# Configuring Kerberos service ticket lifetime in OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have a Mac computer running OS X Yosemite. Its joined to a Microsoft Active Directory and the connections are fine. Now am looking for a way to extend the 10 hours lifetime of Kerberos Service tickets. Even if I configure the domain policy in the DC, Mac issues the tickets only with 10 hours lifetime. On the other hand, Windows computers are issuing tickets with 30 hours lifetime[my configuration in Domain Policy]. I couldn't edit the krb5.conf to extend it, because I need a centralized approach for this.

Note: The reason for extending the ticket's lifetime is that, we have an SSO on premise and Windows systems just work fine. But in OS X systems, Chrome and Firefox requires the Kerberos Service ticket to access these SSO based services and for this the ticket needs to be renewed every 10 hours.

Edit 1: I had already tried locating /etc/krb5.conf but there was no such file.

Comment: After a couple of hours, I reproduced and resolved this in a test environment. Let me know if you're still around to test /verify the quick solution. It involves a simple edit to krb5.conf, for which you can centralize an approach by scripting that file's deployment to all Macs in your realm. If this is acceptable to you.

Comment: You can create a /etc/krb5.conf file on your Mac.  Windows doesn't have one either by default.